# ARR and url rewrite to route to localhost app in IIS webserver

Tags: url-rewriting, reverse-proxy, iis-8.5, arr

I have used ARR and URL rewrite to reverse proxy request from the internet to my local host MVC web app.

The weird thing is some parts of the web app works while others show 404 err:

1) When I type in : mywebsite/Nodewebsite/ - that works

2) When I type in : mywebsite/Nodewebsite/blog - that works

3) When I type in : mywebsite/Nodewebsite/admin - I get my admin page fine but when I try to log on I get a 404 err.

4) When I click on a link on lets say : mywebsite/Nodewebsite/blog that points to another page in my web app, I get a 404 err.

I checked the URL, the path is not right in the 404 err, it points to a location in my web root folder.

It seems whenever I try to access the web app from the internet by typing in a specific URL, it will work but if something redirect to a site it gives a 404 err.